# Can I call a function on ALL base classes in a parameter pack expansion?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there a way to have my run function below call the *run* functions of all the bases classes contained in the parameter pack? Either using standard c++ facilities/libraries or my own template metaprogramming? C++11 preferred but interested in later standards too.

Code simplified to the most basic example. I originally had a use case for this, but now I'm mostly just interested in if it can be done to improve my understanding.

```
template <class ...Bases> class Test : public Bases...
{
public:
    void run()
    {
        // QUESTION: I want to call the run function of ALL the bases, 
        //           Is there a way to do this that compiles and works?
        Bases.run()...;
    }
};

class One
{
public:
    void run() {}
};

class Two
{
public:
    void run() {}
};

int main()
{
    Test<One, Two> test;
    test.run();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it's just usual pack-expansion. The fact that they are your base classes doesn't interfer much.

C++11:

```
int _[]{0, (void(Bases::run()), 0)...};
(void) _;
```

C++17:

```
(void)(Bases::run(), ...);
```

Comment: Ugh, syntax.... specially the c++11 one :)
I understand how that works but would never have thought of that exact syntax. Thanks!

Comment: @jcoder this is kind of the default boilerplate for arbitrary pack-expansion in C++11. Ugly, but robust. Thankfully C++17 fold expressions are now a thing ^^

Comment: For the C++11 syntax, I can understand the meaning of the first line: you initialize an int array and call base classes methods as part of that initialization. But what is the meaning of the second line?

Comment: @SergeBallesta It's just casting int array to void to a`void compiler warning about unused variable.

Comment: The exact code above does not compile in clang 6.0. Changing '(void)(Bases::run(), ...);' to '(Bases::run(), ...);' does compile...

Comment: @user1777224 this sounds like a compiler bug to me. Maybe you should post a separate question.

Comment: does not compile in GCC 9.2 as well, it says "cannot call member function without object"